# Docker container with Oracle SQL + SQL*PLUS

Tags: oracle, docker, sqlplus, ojdbc

I am trying to setup an Oracle SQL Database in a Docker container. This container has to connect to another for automatic data import using a Java program and to a php container.
The whole project worked already on a server from university but now I want to dockerize it. My problem is that I can't define a Docker for my DB that fits my requirements:

1. OCI JDBC
2. Sqlplus
3. Oracle sql
4. Run create db script on startup

---

Here are some results from experimenting with oraclelinux8-instantclient:19
([FROM ghcr.io/oracle/oraclelinux8-instantclient:19](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/pkgs/container/oraclelinux8-instantclient))

When trying to run a simple SELECT query, like SQL> SELECT * FROM Product;

> SP2-0640: Not connected

[root@435cee7e8f84 /]# sqlplus /nolog    -> let’s me use SQL*PLUS, but I cannot log in

When trying to connect log in with any default user access:

> ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified

[root@435cee7e8f84 /]# sqlplus -v

> SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
> Version 19.15.0.0.0
> [root@435cee7e8f84 /]#  lsnrctl status
> bash: lsnrctl: command not found

[root@435cee7e8f84 /]# echo $ORACLE_HOME   -> no result

Comment: The `instantclient` Docker images only contain the client, not the database software. You probably want to start with one of the [Oracle Database dockerfiles](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance). The README.md has a lot of details.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise building an official Oracle Docker image based with the [scripts](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase) provided by Oracle.